# textview link without web-intent

Tags: html, android-intent, textview, android

i have a textview formated with html `Html.fromHtml()`
When i click, for example, in a href, a browser is launched. What I want is to handle that intent, and don't launch browser.

This is the code I have:

```
notic = Html.fromHtml(noti.getDescripcion());                
noticiacorregida = CorrigeLinks(notic);
lbl_descripcion.setText(noticiacorregida);
lbl_descripcion.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

I need to save the URL in a variable, not launch a browser.

Thanks

Comment: Are you wanting to be able to view it in your app?

Comment: yes, view in my app or, for example, if i have a url that is a image resource, launch the image viewer on the phone. i just need to capture URL in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the best I can come up with is make a webview. Use this code. First here is the java.

```
 package com.stackoverflow.images.webview;

import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.widget.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.webkit.*;

public class Site extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image);
        WebView webView = (WebView) 
        findViewById(R.id.webview); 
          webView.loadUrl("http://examplesite.com/yourimage");

      }


}
```

Now here is the XML. Try only to change the package up above in the JAVA and the url.    **Make sure everything is correct with JAVA up above like the onCreate layout**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/webview"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
>

    </WebView>
```